Como puedo añadir un limite de aparicion de contenido de scrollbar?
Es algo peculiar de explicar, pero se resume facil, cree un scrollbar de contenido de temas, e incluso añadi un boton para ocultar ese menu de temas, eso funciona muy bien, pero al ser ya muchos temas se puede scrollear por esa barra de menus, lo que sucede es que al scrollear mucho los temas se ocultan hasta el inicio del background de esa seccion, o dicho de otro modo los temas se colocan por debajo del boton de ocultar menu y se mira mal, me gustaria que se empezaran a ocultar desde antes de llegar al boton, y claro que pudiera ajustar esa altura despues, no se si alguien sepa mas sobre css y me pueda ayudar con eso,


.interacciones {
    background-color: #72698ccf;
    color: #ffff;
}

.interacciones .sidebar {
    margin-top: 180px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #7a748c95;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    overflow-y: auto; /* Añade desplazamiento vertical */
    height: 650px; /* Altura fija del menú */
    position: absolute; /* Cambia a absolute para que no siga la pantalla */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: width 0.3s, padding 0.3s;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.interacciones .sidebar .content {
    max-height: 600px; /* Altura máxima del contenido antes de que aparezca la barra de desplazamiento */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Añade desplazamiento vertical */
    padding: 5px; /* Espacio interno dentro del contenedor */
}

.interacciones .sidebar ul {
    padding: 85px 0 0 0; /* Ajusta el padding superior de la lista de temas */
    margin-top: 0px; /* Ajusta el margen superior de la lista de temas */
    list-style-type: none;
}

.interacciones .sidebar ul li {
    margin-bottom: 5px; /* Ajusta el margen inferior entre cada elemento de la lista */
}

.interacciones .sidebar.collapsed {
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.interacciones .main-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    transition: margin-left 0.3s, max-width 0.3s, padding-right 0.3s;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Añade desplazamiento vertical */
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Para Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Para IE 10+ */
}

.interacciones .main-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0; /* Ancho de la barra de desplazamiento */
    background-color: transparent; /* Color de fondo de la barra de desplazamiento */
}

.interacciones .main-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: transparent; /* Color del "thumb" (la parte deslizante de la barra) */
}

.interacciones .main-content.collapsed {
    margin-left: 0;
    max-width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

.interacciones .content {
    display: none;
}

.interacciones .content.active {
    display: block;
}

.interacciones .navigation-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px; /* Ajusta este valor según sea necesario */
    text-align: right;
    transition: right 0.3s;
}
<div class="interacciones">
            <button id="toggle-sidebar">Ocultar Menú</button>
        <div class="container-bar">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="showContent('tema1')">Definiciones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="showContent('tema2')">Algunas aplicaciones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="showContent('tema3')">Actividad</a></li>
                    <!-- Agrega más temas aquí -->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="navigation-buttons">
                    <button id="prev" onclick="prevContent()">Anterior</button>
                    <button id="next" onclick="nextContent()">Siguiente</button>
                </div>
                <div id="tema1" class="content">
                    <h1>Definiciones</h1>
                    <p>
                        Informacion
                    </p>


                </div>
                <div id="tema2" class="content">
                    <h1>Algunas aplicaciones</h1>
                    <p>
                        Informacion
                    </p>


                </div>
                <div id="tema3" class="content">
                    <h1>Actividad</h1>
                    <p>
                        Informacion
                    </p>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




He editado tu pregunta y he puesto el código a snippet para que asi sea más fácil ejecutarlo. Al hacerlo, veo que el html no cuadra muy bien. Podrias editar tu la pregunta y añadir alguna imagen de tu ejecución en el ordenador en localhost? No se si es problema de stackoverflow o del código. Un Saludo y bienvenido
